# How to solve this ODE system?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems, mathematical-modeling

I have this ODE system:

$\frac{\mathrm{d} x}{\mathrm{d} t}=x-y-(x^{2}+y^{2})x$

$\frac{\mathrm{d} y}{\mathrm{d} t}=x+y-(x^{2}+y^{2})y$

My thought is, firstly make variable change $a=x^{2}$ and $b=y^{2}$, then the system becomes

$\frac{1}{2}a^{2}=a-xy-(a+b)a$

$\frac{1}{2}b^{2}=b+xy-(a+b)b$

Add them together, we get

$\frac{1}{2}(\dot{a}+\dot{b})=a+b-(a+b)^2$

Let $w=a+b$, it becomes $\frac{1}{2}\dot{w}=w-(w)^2$, which can be solved. But we can only know the behavior of $w=a+b=x^{2}+y^{2}$ by this method, I would like to solve it for both $x$ and $y$. I'm not sure I'm on the right truck, can anyone help me?

Comment: Option 1: solve that and plug it in for the factor $x^2+y^2$ and solve the system. Option 2: go to polar coordinates from the beginning.

Comment: Oh I found polar coordinates can solve it, thank you!

Comment: @Ian you should take the time to write that into an answer that the OP can then mark as best answer. That way, the question will not go unanswered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to plug in what you described for the factor $x^2+y^2$ into the system and then solve it.

Another option is to go to polar coordinates up front, so you get

$$\dot{r} \cos(\theta) - r \sin(\theta) \dot{\theta} = r(\cos(\theta)-\sin(\theta)) + r^3 \cos(\theta) \\
\dot{r} \sin(\theta) + r \cos(\theta) \dot{\theta} = r(\cos(\theta)+\sin(\theta)) + r^3 \sin(\theta).$$

From here you can invert $\begin{bmatrix} \cos(\theta) & -r\sin(\theta) \\ \sin(\theta) & r\cos(\theta) \end{bmatrix}$, the inverse is $ \begin{bmatrix} \cos(\theta) & \sin(\theta) \\ -\sin(\theta)/r & \cos(\theta)/r \end{bmatrix}$. Multiplying both sides by that matrix yields a simple system for $\dot{r}$ and $\dot{\theta}$ (they end up being decoupled, actually).